# jQuery toggle multiple classes

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I want to Show/Hide multiple divs on the same class using jQuery toggle.

Currently, the button show/hides **all** divs. How can I make it toggle one div without making the class unique? [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgs2wsz2/).

jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".comment").toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">
    Comment 1
</div>
<button class="button">Show Comment</button>
<br/>
<div class="comment">
    Comment 2
</div>
<button class="button">Show Comment</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the comment relative to the element clicked. In your case it is the previous element to the button, so use `prev()` with `$(this)` (which is the button clicked):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vgs2wsz2/1/

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".comment").toggle();
});
```

Note: The ".comment" in `prev()` is not needed in this case, but makes it more obvious.

e.g. this will do the same:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Interesting! What if it is vise verse: the element is displayed after the button, what function can I use?

Comment: I suppose "next" is appropriate here ;)

Comment: Yes. If the order is reversed, use `next()` :)

Comment: Cheers! Kind of a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785890/jquery-show-hide-next-div