# How can I show and hide just the next element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

How do I show/hide next div? The following code works:

```
jQuery(".edittopic").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".t_edit_cont").toggle();
});
```

... only if the `t_edit_cont` div is right after the `edittopic` button. Currently, I have them in separate DIVs, like this:

```
<div class="t_mod_box">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edittopic" name="send" /> 
</div>

<div class="t_edit_cont">
   Show hide content inside here...
</div>
```

How can I make this work? [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88nuv2e6/1/).

Comment: If you're having only one `.t_edit_cont` in the page, you could simply try: `jQuery(".t_edit_cont").toggle();`.

Comment: @haim770 That's just the problem, I have more than one .t_edit_cont on the page... as shown within the jsfiddle.

Comment: .parent() seems to work! :P

Comment: Try this: `jQuery(this).parent().next(".t_edit_cont").toggle();`

Comment: @haim770 Yup, I figured it out a second before you lol. Please post as answer so I can accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parent()` to point jQuery in the right path:

```
jQuery(this).parent().next(".t_edit_cont").toggle();
```

Yet, a cleaner and more reliable approach would be to associate the clicked button and the div somehow.

For example (using `data-` attributes):

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edittopic" data-id="1" name="send" />

<div class="t_edit_cont" data-id="1">
Show hide content inside here...
</div>
```

Then:

```
jQuery(".edittopic").click(function() {
    var btnId = $(this).data('id');
    jQuery('.t_edit_cont[data-id=' + btnId + ']').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to select parent before doing `.next()`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88nuv2e6/6/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".edittopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".t_edit_cont").toggle();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so you want show hide as you want your FAQ, hopefully this is helpful for you

http://jsfiddle.net/indianwebdesigner/yhvm4duq/

if not then please leave a message

**HTML**

```
<div class="mod_wrap">
    <div class="t_mod_box">
        <a href="#" class="edittopic" name="send">Toggle</a>
    </div>

    <div class="t_edit_cont">
       Show hide content inside here... 1
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(this).parents(".mod_wrap").find(".t_edit_cont").slideToggle();
```

Comment: Thanks for the Question, Please check : 
http://jsfiddle.net/indianwebdesigner/yhvm4duq/