# How can I hide or show input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I hide inputs tag or show that, when I click on span tag.

I want click on each of span tag and show inputs tag and hide span tag related that row and other row only show span tag. other rows like this row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ID, tmp_ID, count, flag = 0;
  $("tr").click(function() {
    ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#s" + ID).hide();
    $("#num" + ID).show();
    $("#btn" + ID).show();
  });

  $("btn" + ID).click(function() {
    $("#s" + ID).show();
    $("#num" + v).hide();
    $("#btn" + ID).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.num {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
  <th>Name</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td class="noEdit">
        <span id="s1">1</span>
        <div id="btn1" class="num">click me!</div>
        <input type="number" id="num1" class="num" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>
        <span id="s2">2</span>
        <div id="btn2" class="num">click me!</div>
        <input type="number" id="num2" class="num" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td>
        <span id="s3">3</span>
        <div id="btn1" class="num">click me!</div>
        <input type="number" id="num3" class="num" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td>
        <span id="s4">4</span>
        <div>
          <input id="btn4" class="num" type="submit" value="Release" />
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="num4" class="num" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You will never trigger $("btn"+ID).click(function()  because at the time you load the document, the ID is null. There's your problem

Comment: Thank you for your replay, what's solution?

Comment: Your english is really hard to understand, please try to explain again what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You can use jquery toggle function for more info refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785317/jquery-toggle-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really hard to understand, but what I got is, that you want to hide and show the input in a row on click of it's row's span element?

Try to bind an click event to each span, and access it's parent and then the input to toggle it.

```
$('#tableCompleted span').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
      $('#tableCompleted input').hide();
      $(this).parent().find('input').first().show();
   });
});
```

This code will hide all input-fields in the table and only show the input, which corresponding span tag was clicked.

If you want to hide the span in that row, use this code : http://jsfiddle.net/hy82ssy2/

Comment: Thank you for your replay, when i click on each row, that's row must show inputs tag and other rows must show only span.

Comment: Here is the fork with my working solution http://jsfiddle.net/z816mL78/

Comment: Thank you, It's worked, and i want click on "click me!" and hide all inputs, how to use this?

Comment: analogous to the click function I posted.
Please note that Stack Overflow is not a platform where everything is coded for you.
Try to understand what my code does. Read the jQuery Documentation, please.

Answer (score 1):

Give each "btn" a class, say "sub-btn", like so:

```
<div id = "btn1" class="num sub-btn">click me!</div>
```

then in your code, do something like this:

```
$(".sub-btn").click(function()
    {
        ID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/gi,'');//removes all non-numeric character in id to get number
        $("#s" + ID).show();
        $("#num" + ID).hide();
        $("#btn" + ID).hide();
    });
```

**Note:** You have 2 ids with btn1 in your example